# Is there a way to add fiddler certificates for https decryption that will work across various users on a machine?

Tags: fiddler

Is there a way to add fiddler certificates for https decryption that will work across various users on a machine? Or is it always user specific?

Answer (score 1):

http://groups.google.com/group/httpfiddler/browse_thread/thread/b6acb3d48932d678
You can copy the Fiddler root certificate into the machine's Trusted 
Root store (using mmc.exe to load the MACHINE's copy of certmgr.msc) 
but that likely won't do exactly what you want because it sounds like 
you imagine you'd run the Fiddler instance within each user's account 
rather than just having one instance run centrally?  That would be 
problematic because when it's actually re-signing the traffic, 
Fiddler's looking in the user's personal store for the root 
certificate to use. I could easily change Fiddler to look in the 
machine store first, although I'm not sure what the implications would 
be for the private key's accessibility.

You'd probably be better off just having the user enable HTTPS 
decryption themselves. If the goal is to simply capture traffic, you 
can use FiddlerCap (fiddlercap.com) and the HTTPS option is right on 
the home screen.